# How do create a reference to a member of an array

Tags: c++, class

How can I make a reference of a member of an array in a class?

something like:

```
class ASD{
    int bb[4];
    int& up = bb[0] // <- error need to const
    int& down= bb[1] // <- samething
    int& right= bb[2] // <- samething
    int& left= bb[3] // <- samething
};
```

this is so I can do this:

```
int main(){
    ASD asd();
    asd.bb[1] = 5;
    // or
    for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
        asd.bb[i] =i;
    }
    // and still be able to do this:
    asd.left = 50;
    //which will be equal to asd.bb[3] = 50
    return 0;
}
```

One more thing. Do you know how can I make the reverse:

something like:

```
class ASD{
    
    int up;  
    int down; 
    int right; 
    in& left; 
    int*& bb = &up; // <- error
};
```

so I can do this:

```
ASD asd;
asd.bb[1] = 20;// which is equal to asd.down = 20
```

Comment: Added the missing `;`s and it compiles clean for me g++ 5.1.0  Note that you will have further problem trying to copy and assign instances of `ASD`.

Comment: `error need to const` is not a real error that any compiler would give. Post the real error, verbatim. Also, which compiler you are using and which switches you passed to it; you're probably not telling it to use a new enough C++ version.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/bqVKzR). You should add a [mcve] and the error messages to your question. If you did that (and fixed the missing `;`) you could have realized that there are none  :P

Comment: @underscore_d why? :D

Comment: Are you asking me why you should post useful information that enables readers to do anything other than guess at your problem?

Comment: please don't ask two questions in one post. Ask a separate question. But please do pay attention to the quality of it. Please format your code properly and provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score -2):

Your code works as intended. Well... with small adjustments that are unrelated with your main issue:

1. make the members public
2. add `;`
3. due to [most verxing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) `ASD asd();` is interpreted as a function. Use `ASD asd;` or better yet `ASD asd{};`:

```
class ASD
{
public:
    int bb[4];
    int& up = bb[0];
    int& down= bb[1];
    int& right= bb[2];
    int& left= bb[3];
};

int main()
{
    ASD asd{};
    asd.bb[1] = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
        asd.bb[i] =i;
    }

    asd.left = 50;
    return 0;
}
```

The other problem that doesn't allow you to use this code is that you are compiling in an old `C++` standard. Use at least `c++11`. It supports in-class initialization, which is what you are doing.

---

If, for whatever reason you still want to use C++98 then you need to initialize the member references in a c-tor initialization list:

```
class ASD
{
public:
    int bb[4];
    int& up = bb[0];
    int& down;
    int& right;
    int& left;

    ASD()
        : up(bb[0]),
        down(bb[1]),
        right(bb[2]),
        left(bb[3])
    {}

};

int main()
{
    ASD asd;
    asd.bb[1] = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
        asd.bb[i] =i;
    }
    asd.left = 50;    
}
```

But I highly recommend using the newer (well, it's not that new anymore) standard.